# How to inlcude a javascript file into a Vaadin 14 litlement component

Tags: vaadin

How can I include a JavaScript library file into a LitElement template component in Vaadin 14? I would like to load a file and execute it automatically when the component is attached to the component hierarchy.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to load an external library and use it in LitElement but also manage it in Java you can build a Java class:

```
@JsModule("./my-test-component.ts")
@Tag("my-test-component")
public class MyTestComponent extends Component {

    public MyTestComponent() {
    }


    public String getTest() {
        return getElement().getProperty("test");
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        getElement().setProperty("test", test);
    }

}
```

The tag is important since this is the link between the JavaScript/Typescript and the Java.

And you can create a LitElement with Typescript (for Vaadin 14.5+) or just JavaScript:

```
import {css, customElement, html, LitElement, property} from 'lit-element';


@customElement('my-test-component')
export class MyTestComponent extends LitElement {
    static get styles() {
        return css`
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
        `;
    }
    @property({ attribute: true })
    public test: String = "test";

    /**
     * Main method of the component
     *
     */
    render() {
        return html`Test attribute ${this.test}"`;
    }

}
```

In that case, it doesn't do anything with an external library.
The next step is to read the documentation of the external library and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

LitElement files are normal JS modules, so you can use the `import` keyword to import libraries or methods.

```
import {foo} from 'library';

export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
  ...
}
```